# "Invalid field selection emailAddress" from service.permissions().list with Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the field 'emailAddress' from the Google Drive REST API using the python client. I am using the permission endpoint.

I have tried using the `list()` and the `get()` function and only `get()` works.

---

list() request

```py
# my-file-id is a placeholder

service.permissions().list(fileId = 'my-file-id', fields = 'emailAddress').execute()
```

returns:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/my-file-id/permissions?fields=emailAddress&alt=json returned "Invalid field selection emailAddress">
```

---

get() request

```py
# my-permission-id and my-file-id are placeholders

service.permissions().get(fileId = 'my-file-id', permissionId = 'my-permission-id', fields = 'emailAddress').execute()
```

returns:

```
{'emailAddress': 'expected@email.com'}
```

---

Using the `*` endpoint with `list()` returns all the expected fields:

```py
# my-file-id is a placeholder
service.permissions().list(fileId='my-file-id',fields='*').execute()
```

returns:

```
{'kind': 'drive#permissionList', 'permissions': [{'kind': 'drive#permission', 'id': '****', 'type': 'user', 'emailAddress': 'expected@email.com', 'role': 'writer', 'displayName': '****', 'photoLink': '****', 'deleted': False}, {'kind': 'drive#permission', 'id': '****', 'type': 'user', 'emailAddress': 'expected@email.com', 'role': 'owner', 'displayName': '****', 'deleted': False}]}
```

In this case there are two users with permissions on this particular file.

According to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) I should be able to query `emailAddress` through the `fields` parameter.

Is this a problem with the API or is it because there are multiple permission objects in the response?

Comment: Are you not getting the list of files when using list() you may have to use something like this  `service.permissions().list(fileId = 'my-file-id', fields = files('emailAddress')).execute()
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to retrieve a list of only `emailAddress` using `fields` from drive.permissions.list.

If my understanding is correct, how about using the following `fields`? Please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
service.permissions().list(fileId = 'my-file-id', fields = 'emailAddress').execute()
```

#### To:

```
service.permissions().list(fileId = 'my-file-id', fields = 'permissions/emailAddress').execute()
```

#### Reference:

- [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Yes this works perfectly. I am sorry I haven't gotten to your answer sooner, I have been very busy with work.

On reflection since the google api client is using a REST API the endpoint is a subset of `permissions`.

Comment: @Collin Arnett No problem. Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.