How are list the permissions of shared drive in app-script
I'm trying list the permissions of shared drive but several items are undefined
function listAllSharedDrives() {
  let pageToken = null;
  let page;
  let pageperm;
  let contador=0;
  let idunidad;

  Logger.clear();
  //do {
    page = Drive.Drives.list({
      pageSize: 1,
      pageToken: pageToken,
      q: 'memberCount = 1',
      //fields isn't documented in Drive API v3, but is necessary to evoid undefined fields.
      fields: 'nextPageToken, drives(id, name, createdTime)',
      useDomainAdminAccess: true
    });
    const drives = page.drives;
    if (drives) 
    // Print the drive's name.
      for (const drive of drives) {
        contador+=1;
        console.log('Id: %s Nombre: %s Creado en: %s', drive.id, drive.name, drive.createdTime);
        
        pageperm = Drive.Permissions.list (drive.id,{
          supportsAllDrives: true,
          useDomainAdminAccess: true
        })
        const lospermisos = pageperm.permissions;
        if (lospermisos)
         for (const mipermiso of lospermisos) {
           console.log('Permiso ID: %s\nDisplayName: %s\nTipo: %s\nKind: %s\nRole: %s\nEmail: %s\nDominio: %s\nExpirationTime: %s\nDeleted: %s\nView: %s\nPendingOwner: %s',mipermiso.id,mipermiso.displayName,mipermiso.type,mipermiso.kind,mipermiso.role,mipermiso.emailAddress,mipermiso.domain,mipermiso.expirationTime,mipermiso.deleted,mipermiso.view,mipermiso.pendingOwner);
           if (mipermiso.PermissionDetails)
             for (const detalle of mipermiso.PermissionDetails) {
               console.log('Detalle permissionType: %s inheritedFrom: %s Role: %s Inherited: %s',detalle.PermissionType,detalle.inheritedFrom,detalle.role,detalle.inherited)
             }
         }
        console.log('');
      }
  //  pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  //} while (pageToken);
  console.log('Total de unidades compartidas %d',contador);  
}

OUTPUT:
Información Id: 0APeuZG... Nombre: UAL Creado en: 2024-01-15T10:33:37.635Z
Información Permiso ID: 156621468...
DisplayName: undefined
Tipo: user
Kind: drive#permission
Role: organizer
Email: undefined
Dominio: undefined
ExpirationTime: undefined
Deleted: undefined
View: undefined
PendingOwner: undefined

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, how about using fields: "*" for Drive.Permissions.list as follows?
From:
pageperm = Drive.Permissions.list (drive.id,{
  supportsAllDrives: true,
  useDomainAdminAccess: true
})

To:
pageperm = Drive.Permissions.list(drive.id, {
  supportsAllDrives: true,
  useDomainAdminAccess: true,
  fields: "*" // Added
})

Note:

In the case of fields: "*", all fields are returned. If you want to restrict the fields, you can also manually set it instead of *.
From your sample OUTPUT: value, I guessed that you could retrieve the values with useDomainAdminAccess: true.

Reference:

Method: drives.list of Drive API v3


Thanks you. It's work ok. But the optional parameter "fields" isn't not documented in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/list

@Antonio Casado Thank you for replying. About Thanks you. It's work ok., welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

@Antonio Casado About your new question But the optional parameter "fields" isn't not documented in developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/…, in this case, please check Response body of "Method: permissions.list". For example, when you want only a value of permission ID and display name, please use fields: "permissions(id,displayName)".

The confusion is in the use of individual fields. If you use "fields = 'emailAddress'", that fails. You must use "fields: 'permissions/id,permissions/emailAddress'". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56295941/invalid-field-selection-emailaddress-from-service-permissions-list-with-goog

@Antonio Casado Thank you for replying. "fields: 'permissions/id,permissions/emailAddress'" can also be modified to "fields: "permissions(id,emailAddress)". I guess that this official document might also be useful. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/fields-parameter
